# I added a Curl.php file in another location. Now I have a Fatal Error when accessing the backend of my store

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, class, curl

I added a Curl.php file in another location. Now I have a Fatal Error when accessing the backend of my store. (Yes, I deleted the other location already, but I still receive the error) Does anyone have any insight on this? Help is much appreciated.

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1):

Clear/flush the cache, and remove the generated folder. If the issue persists, rename your class to a more unique name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new at Magento. Where might I do that? Both clear/flush and rename class?....... I host on Hostmonster.

Comment: In the terminal in your project directory run `bin/magento cache:flush` and `sudo rm -rf generated/code/*  `. Renaming that class is just change it from `Curl` to lets say  `CustomCurl`

Comment: Okay, renaming the curl file didn't work but I don't know where the terminal in my project directory is to run those codes.

Comment: If you are using linux open a terminal window and navigate to your project. You can do that by `ctrl+alt+t` to open a teminal and then `cd /var/www/projectName`